# Delphi OpenPictureDialog behave different on different app

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm using Delphi 10.1 on Windows 10
When I run the OpenPictureDialog.Execute command
on some app it's open File Explorer with a preview area and on others without.
I have exactly the same properties on both cases.
What can cause the difference?
Thanks Sorin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Without examples it may be difficult for anyone to answer this question. Please take a look at the help on how to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do both applications have runtime themes enabled?

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetOpenFileName;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameA';
function GetOpenFileNameA;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameA';
function GetOpenFileNameW;      external commdlg32  name 'GetOpenFileNameW';
```

In older versions on Delphi it used a Windows API function in comdlg32.dll to open a file. I would think it is the same in newer versions. What you see in terms of preview etc. is down to Windows settings.
The dialog shows to the user will be consistent with other file open dialogs they see on their system.